# Pushing files from one account to other in github

Tags: github, push, git-remote

Iam trying to push some changes to other account from another account but it is giving me permission error.I checked the github settings but everything there seems to be right.Can anybody help me with this?

[image]

**EDIT:**
I tried changing my user name and email too still it is giving same error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some info about the transfer process which might help you

When a repository is transferred between two user accounts, issue assignments are left intact. When you transfer a repository from a user account to an organization, issues assigned to members in the organization remain intact, and all other issue assignees are cleared. Only owners in the organization are allowed to create new issue assignments. When you transfer a repository from an organization to a user account, only issues assigned to the repository's owner are kept, and all other issue assignees are removed.

If the transferred repository contains a GitHub Pages site, then links to the Git repository on the Web and through Git activity are redirected. However, we don't redirect GitHub Pages associated with the repository.

All links to the previous repository location are automatically redirected to the new location. When you use `git clone`, `git fetch`, or `git push` on a transferred repository, these commands will redirect to the new repository location or URL. However, to avoid confusion, I strongly recommend updating any existing local clones to point to the new repository URL. You can do this by using git remote on the command line:

```
$ git remote set-url origin new_url
```

Comment: No, it is showing the same error . same permission error.

Answer (score 0):

**Add the collaborator from the initial account (the git account having the repo) and the second account can accept the invitation to be a collaborator**

This allows you to change and push the code from different Id also.